# Who will do design for this lifehacks SE and Can I able to give suggestions?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, design

Many SE sites have their own specific & meaningful designs on upvote/downvote arrows, fonts, header images, etc. I love Gaming, Christianity, travel etc..

I think these are designed by SE team may with be with outside designers. I would like to know if there are anyways to give suggestions to SE team.

Comment: It will be done by someone who the Stack gods choose (usually a designer on staff)

Comment: That will come if the site makes it to graduation.

Comment: Jumping the gun, perhaps?

Comment: idk that you're jumping the gun.  If you click the "Read [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)" link at the top of the page, it's in there -- *with* the answer.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Thanks, It is mentioned they will consider if community stands, but no further details.

Comment: Don't put too much stake in those seven questions - they're pretty out-of-date. Peruse [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/165581) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the already linked blog article: ["The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

> #### 6. What should our logo and site design look like?
>
> This one is pretty straightforward. Solicit contributions, throw out ideas, post
> preliminary (or finished) designs, and be supportive and respectful of
> other people’s ideas and creativity.
>
> We have designers on staff who will actively help come up with site
> designs but, if an idea stemming from the community stands out as
> exceptional, we are happy to use it.